# Codeigniter multifile upload

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2

```
$this->upload->display_errors()
```

shows the errors for all the files I am trying to upload.
How can I show the error for each file field ?
for example, if the user can upload 5 files and the third file is to big, I want to be able to tell him that this specific file is to big.

Comment: why don't you do client side checks via jQuery for some common errors?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are after is not built-in to the CI upload library. Here's CI's `$this->upload->display_errors()` method:

```
function display_errors($open = '<p>', $close = '</p>')
    {
        $str = '';
        foreach ($this->error_msg as $val)
        {
            $str .= $open.$val.$close;
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

It returns all the errors as a single string. You would need to adjust this accordingly, perhaps to return an array with the `key` for the respective file field.

You could use the `$_FILES` superglobal before hand, and check each field for errors, and then if there are no errors, call CI's `do_upload()`